# how to filter the ng-model value using angularjs directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-filter, angularjs-ng-model

i'm attaching the date element in template as

```
<input type="date" ng-model="experience.date_start" date-ob>
```

The ng-model is binding value as a string to the date. For it i need to convert this string to object(new Date(experience.date_start)). I'm trying to achieve this context via directive called as **date-ob**

```
.directive('dateOb', function(){
 return {
 require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$parsers.push(function(value) {
            console.log('parser!', value);
            return new Date(value);
        });
        ctrl.$formatters.push(function(value) {
            console.log('formatter!', value);
            return value;
        });
    }       
}
});
```

It throws

> Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2014-08-28` to be a date
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/ngModel/datefmt?p0=2014-08-28

How should be the code in date-ob directive for it?
i'm newbie to .directive please give me the solution with explanation????..

Comment: update your directive code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [formatters and parsers](http://alexperry.io/angularjs/2014/12/10/parsers-and-formatters-angular.html) - they are used for exactly things like these. Parsers change how the value from the view will be stored in the model. While formatters change how the value from the model will be displayed in the view.

Using a directive you could do something like this:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('wrapperDirective', function(){
  return {
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.experience = {date_start: '2015-01-01'};
    }
  };
})
.directive('dateOb', function(){
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      // view --> model (change date to string)
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(viewValue){
        return viewValue.toISOString();
      });

      // model --> view (change string to date)
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(modelValue){
        return new Date(modelValue);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" wrapper-directive>
    <p>Date is: {{experience.date_start}}</p>
    <input type="date" ng-model="experience.date_start" date-ob>  
</div>
```

Comment: it throws an error "Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2014-08-28` to be a date"

Comment: Look at my snippet, you can run it directly. Maybe I missunderstood what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: In your snippet input type does not update the value, only<p> is updating value.?

Comment: The input element updates the value on the model - which you can see as the paragraph prints the model-value directly to view. The model is stored as a string - while I parse it to a Date-object before sending it to the input (input date requires a date)

Comment: when page is loading the initial experience.date_start (2015-01-01) value is want to assign the input element.. but here mm/dd/yyyy why?

Comment: did you get my issue?

Comment: solved bro need to return object in ngModel.$formatters.push

Comment: I had swapped the parser and formatter. The parser should parse to string. while the formatter should make a date-object.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this . it solved my problem.

```
.directive('dateOb', function(){
 return {
    scope: {
     dateModel :'=ngModel'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.$watch('dateModel',function(n,o){
            if(!n instanceOf Date)
            {
              scope.dateModel = new Date(dateModel);
            }
        });
    }       
}
});
```